# OpenNI devices and USB 3.0

Tags: openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

None of our OpenNI devices (Kinect, Xtion, PrimeSense Carmine) work when attached to USB 3.0 ports on our computers running ROS Fuerte and Ubuntu 12.04. These computers all have either NEC/Renesas uPD720200 controllers or Intel Panther Point (integrated in the chipset) controllers.

Has anyone successfully used these sensors on USB 3.0 ports?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56110/openni-devices-and-usb-3.0/) by [Calder](https://answers.ros.org/users/4279/calder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2013-02-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-02-24**:
As far as I am aware, that is an OpenNI and/or Ubuntu issue, not a ROS issue. I haven't seen anyone get USB 3.0 to work with any of these sensors.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-24**:
I believe there are recent Linux kernel updates in Precise to fix some USB 3.0 problems. Not sure exactly what problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On Ubuntu 12.10, USB 3.0 issues have been solved in majority.I know it doesn't concern your case, but maybe you could think about updating to 12.10 and Groovy (for which all my USB 3.0 works).

Bests regards,

Steph

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We had some trouble with a similar (the same?) problem. Using ROS Fuerte, MS Kinect (original XBox-version) and USB 3.0 on Ubuntu 12.04, x64.

I don't remember the exact specifics, but there was a problem with some low-level kernel stuff and the way it handled some usb-communication. After reading up on some related mailing-lists, it seemed that the kernel version of 12.04 wouldn't work as bugfixes were in preparation for newer kernel versions only. We ended up with upgrading to kernel 3.4.2 and our kinects are streaming happily ever since :-)

Edit: just stumbled upon another ros.answer which gives more specifics about the exact problems with the older kernel: http://answers.ros.org/question/9179/kinect-and-usb-30/

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-02-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3